# bash command line append to variable will prepend instead

Tags: bash, variables, loops, for-loop, append

in shell scripts I usually append a string to variable with "${variable} end". However, I have a file "file.txt" in which I want all lines to be appended by "end". So command line I do, for instance, `` for i in `cat file.txt`; do echo "${i} end"; done ``. But the word "end" (pluse the space) will not be appended but appended. The same thing happends when I use a while loop. Could anybody tell me what is going on right there? I am using GNU bash version 4.2.37 on LinuxMint13 64bit (both Cinammon and Mate).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "[...] will not be appended but appended." What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a while loop instead of a for loop, [as explained here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor?highlight=%28loop%29%7C%28over%29%7C%28lines%29%7C%28in%29%7C%28file%29).

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line end"
done < "file.txt"
```

Comment: Hi, no sorry I forget to add I tried it with a while loop, too!

Comment: I could provide a screenshot. I am very confused with this

Comment: @WayneJhukie Note that `$line` does not have brackets around it. Otherwise, I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be your syntax - don't forget `do`.  That is:

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do echo "${i} end"; done
```

If you're asking how to make a new file with "end" appended to each line, try this:

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do echo "${i} end" >> some_new_file; done
```

Comment: don't use `for in in cat file` instead use `while read do ... done < file.txt`

Comment: Hi Matt, I am sorry, I did not forget the do (just a mistake with my post) :/

Answer (score 0):

Is using a loop the only option?  If all you want to do is append something to the end of every line, it's probably easier to use `sed`:

```
sed -ie 's/.*/& end/' file.txt
```